# How to detect fling on TextView without cancelling scroll?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, onfling

Trying to detect a fling on a  TextView using simpleGestureDetector:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    textContent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }        
    });
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            if(foo) {
                fooBar();
                return true;
            }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

This works in the sense that my code `fooBar()` is run if the conditions `foo` are met, but the problem I find is that when the conditions aren't met, returning super.onFling() causes the fling to be cancelled, it seems, since the textview scroll no longer continues after the finger is lifted on a fling.  Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_area"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dip"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way I can keep the ordinary scroll behaviour and still detect the fling?

EDIT: Sorry, my bad, this had nothing to do with the gesture detector, it was just because I took the TextView out of its ScrollView - for some reason it seems TextViews don't have smooth (inertia) scrolling like ScrollViews.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between scroll and fling events is that the user lifts his finger in the end of the movement in order to make it a fling. (and the speed is higher).

Therefore, I think it is not possible to combine both events as they are (too) similar to detect (before ending them) which one is being performed.
Also from a user perspective, using both gestures at the same time is confusing (due to the similarity).

So the answer is: no there is no way to keep the ordinary scroll behaviour and still detect the fling.

(at least I tried in the past and did not succeed in using both events in a proper way)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just confused as to why I can't pass through to super.onFling() (or even just return false) and have the scrolling carry on as normal as though nothing happened.

Comment: As I answered: I do not think the system is able to detect which event should be fired, so it picks one and sticks to it. And you are not able anymore to choose for 'the other one'. At least that is how it 'felt' to me when I tried to use both events in the past. My solution was to one pick/use one of these events at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will be your problem, but why do you return `true` if your condition is met? If you don't want the event to be consumed, you should return `false` (or `super.onFling`). That's what the return value is for.

Comment: I do want it to be consumed if the conditions are met (flinging left or right) since I want that to change the textview content.

Comment: Consuming the event means that the event will not be sent further to other listeners. It does not mean that it will not be processed by your code. When you return `true` upon lifting your finger, the fling event is detected, but it is consumed, so the default scroll listener does not receive the event. You should only consume an event when you want to *replace* the default behaviour, not when you want to *extend* it.

Comment: I do want to replace it; I'm not concerned that it scrolls if the conditions are met, I am going to then replace the entire textview... anyway, this isn't my question - I'm concerned with what to do when the conditions are not met.